# How to trace a message if 3 movieclips was clicked?

Tags: actionscript-3

I am building a simple game in flash in actionscipt 3.
I want when the user click on the 3 movieclips on the stage to trace a message like "Thanks for clicking all 3 movieclips!"

this message have to appear once he click on the 3 not only on one.

any ideas :)

Answer (score 1):

You want to store if they have been clicked where each of you listeners can access, for example:

```
var clicked1:Boolean = false;
var clicked2:Boolean = false;
var clicked3:Boolean = false;
```

Then inside of your action listener method(s):

```
function listenerMethod1(e:MouseEvent):void {
  clicked1 = true;
  checkIfAllClicked();
}

function listenerMethod2(e:MouseEvent):void {
  clicked2 = true;
  checkIfAllClicked();
}

function listenerMethod3(e:MouseEvent):void {
  clicked3 = true;
  checkIfAllClicked();
}
```

etc... (alternatively you can handle all 3 movieClip events in the same handler method). Don't forget the checking function:

```
function checkIfAllClicked(){
  if(clicked1 && clicked2 && clicked3){
    trace("Thanks for clicking all 3 movieclips!");
  }
}
```

Depending on what you are doing you can have a reset method as well to reset all 3 to false.

If you have a big mass of movieclips you can consider using a collection, such as a `Vector<Boolean>`.

Comment: i think i will need to add this as well right : 
box1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, listenerMethod1);
box2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, listenerMethod2);
box3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, listenerMethod3);

Thanks :)

Comment: You are correct, any listener method should have a corresponding addEventListner() that will call it

Answer (score 0):

Or you could have a single function that all buttons use:

```
var count:uint = 0;

function buttonPress(e:MouseEvent):void {
  count++;

if (count == 3) {
trace("Thanks for clicking all 3 movieclips!");

//reset count if required
//count = 0;
}
```

}

Comment: The Only thing is that the user might click the movieclip more than once...and i want it to count just the first click from each..
Thanks :)